# Nautilus font size depends on how fast I log in

Tags: 14.04, unity, 16.04, nautilus, fonts

I recently updated from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS and I am now experiencing a curios bug:

When I first set up Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I chose a bigger font size for Nautilus and the desktop, as I have a HDPI display, and the default font looked tiny.

Now after the update on 16.04, the login screen will first have the *tiny font*, and after about 7 seconds, it will **switch** to the *normal font*.

I am experiencing the following bug:

If I log in during the first 7 seconds, the desktop and Nautilus will have the *tiny font* and will **remain like this** for the rest of the session.

However, if I log in after the first 7 seconds, and the font of the start screen has switched to *normal*, the desktop and Nautilus font sizes will be *normal* as well.

How can I fix this bug so that -- even if I log in immediately -- Nautilus will have the correct font size?

Comment: Really interesting question  (bizarre bugs are fascinating), but if it actually is a bug you might be better off reporting it on Launchpad, where the devs are more likely to see it.

Comment: Thanks, as it is such a bizarre problem, I am not really sure if it is an actual bug in the OS. Maybe I just broke something in the settings when originally setup the font sizes in 14.04. Does anyone have an idea what it could be?